# Jquery find a element inside a div

Tags: jquery

I am having a bit problem accessing the children using jquery.
I have a html like this

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <div>
      <table id="customer">
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i have this jquery like this

```
var parentDiv = $('#wrapper');
var table= parentDiv.html();
console.log(table);
```

output

```
<div>
        <div>
          <table id="customer">
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
table = $(table); //jquery object
//i want the table customer of this object
```

What i want is to get the table customer. How can i do that using var table? .each() only fetches divs as well as .find().

something like this

```
$(innerHtml).each(); //or whatever function i can use to get the table
```

Comment: use `$('#customer')` no need to find

Comment: Yah i can do that but what i want is to get the table of innerHtml.

Comment: which div inner html ?

Comment: $('#customer').parent().html();

Comment: how about `$('#custommer')[0].outerHTML` ?

Comment: `what i want is to get the table of innerHtml` What do you mean???

Comment: @wolf--  my "var innerHtml".

Comment: this is not making sense . you want table or the parent divs of table ?

Comment: @n4mi It would be `var parentDiv = $("div:has(>#customer)");
var innerHtml = parentDiv.html();` But it doesn't make sense, just use as suggested above `$('#custommer')[0].outerHTML` or `$('#custommer').prop('outerHTML')` because IDs must be unqiue on document context. Anyway, this is still quite unclear what the result you are expecting... Why don't you simply tell us with an concrete example what you are looking for instead of using some terms you obviously don't master?!

Comment: @mhasan-- i need it to be like that cause i want to replicate the table for later use

Comment: @n4mi So you just want to clone it: `$('#customer').clone().attr('id','newIdToAvoidDuplicate')` ?!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#customer').parent('div').html();
```